# Use IMPORTXML to retrieve a table row that contains a certain term

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I want to use Google Sheets to import specific financial data from company filings.

Specifically, I want FFO, which you can see at the bottom of the table on page 63 here:

https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0000888491/000088849120000048/ohi-20200930x10q.htm

I tried using

```
//tr[contains(.,'FFO')]/td[2])[1]
```

But no luck.

Every company's filing will have a different number of tables, so I can't use table index.

Answer (score 1):

This page is loaded via javascript ("This application relies heavily on JavaScript, you will need to allow JavaScript to use this application." and "Below is populated dynamically VIA JS"), so importxml will be inefficient at all. Moreover, the data here are not contained in a json and are called after the page has been loaded first. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun